# R GSRUB function

Tags: r, function, gsub

Working with a public data set where a variable classification(s), stores code(s) that describe the type(s) of licenses associated with a LicenseNo. Any license can have between 1 and 19 different concurrent license types associated with a licenseNo which is distinct. A function would seem the right strategy to split Classifications into [1:19] new columns Classification1:Classification19. Not sure where to get started. I also need to convert the codes to descriptions, have created a table to support this piece given what I've read from the web site thinking it could be pulled in as a rda file.  Not sure where to get started.

[image]

```
LicenseNo <- c("1000002","1000003","1000012","1000015","1000026")
Classifications <- c("C57","C-6","B","C60| C51", "HAZ| C36| C10| A| B| C57| C-2| C-8| C12| C21| C27| C29| C35| C42| C45| C39| C50| C51| C31")
data <- data.frame(LicenseNo,Classifications)
View(data)

Descriptions <- c("Cabinet, Millwork and Finish Carpentry Contractor","General Building Contractor",
                  "Well Drilling Contractor", "Structural Steel Contractor","Welding Contractor",
                  "Hazardous Substance Removal Certification","Plumbing Contractor","Electrical Contractor",
                  "General Engineering Contractor", "Insulation and Acoustical Contractor")
Classifications <- c("C-6","B","C57","C51","C60","HAZ","C36","C10","A","C-2")
class_type <- data.frame(Descriptions,Classifications)
View(class_type)
```

Ultimately, looking to create the following output,...only listed 4 classification for observation 1000026 to simplify.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
# library(tidyr) # unnest, pivot_*
out <- data %>%
  mutate(Classifications = strsplit(Classifications, "[|\\s]+")) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(Classifications) %>%
  mutate(Classifications = trimws(Classifications)) %>%
  left_join(class_type, by = "Classifications") %>%
  mutate(Classifications = coalesce(Descriptions, Classifications)) %>%
  select(-Descriptions)

out
# # A tibble: 24 x 2
#    LicenseNo Classifications                                  
#    <chr>     <chr>                                            
#  1 1000002   Well Drilling Contractor                         
#  2 1000003   Cabinet, Millwork and Finish Carpentry Contractor
#  3 1000012   General Building Contractor                      
#  4 1000015   Welding Contractor                               
#  5 1000015   Structural Steel Contractor                      
#  6 1000026   Hazardous Substance Removal Certification        
#  7 1000026   Plumbing Contractor                              
#  8 1000026   Electrical Contractor                            
#  9 1000026   General Engineering Contractor                   
# 10 1000026   General Building Contractor                      
# # ... with 14 more rows
```

**Note**: I `coalesce`d the description and original classification because there are missing components. For instance, without `coalesce` we'll see:

```r
out <- data %>%
  mutate(Classifications = strsplit(Classifications, "[|\\s]+")) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(Classifications) %>%
  mutate(Classifications = trimws(Classifications)) %>%
  left_join(class_type, by = "Classifications")
print(out,n=99)
# # A tibble: 24 x 3
#    LicenseNo Classifications Descriptions                                     
#    <chr>     <chr>           <chr>                                            
#  1 1000002   C57             Well Drilling Contractor                         
#  2 1000003   C-6             Cabinet, Millwork and Finish Carpentry Contractor
#  3 1000012   B               General Building Contractor                      
#  4 1000015   C60             Welding Contractor                               
#  5 1000015   C51             Structural Steel Contractor                      
#  6 1000026   HAZ             Hazardous Substance Removal Certification        
#  7 1000026   C36             Plumbing Contractor                              
#  8 1000026   C10             Electrical Contractor                            
#  9 1000026   A               General Engineering Contractor                   
# 10 1000026   B               General Building Contractor                      
# 11 1000026   C57             Well Drilling Contractor                         
# 12 1000026   C-2             Insulation and Acoustical Contractor             
# 13 1000026   C-8             <NA>                                             
# 14 1000026   C12             <NA>                                             
# 15 1000026   C21             <NA>                                             
# 16 1000026   C27             <NA>                                             
# 17 1000026   C29             <NA>                                             
# 18 1000026   C35             <NA>                                             
# 19 1000026   C42             <NA>                                             
# 20 1000026   C45             <NA>                                             
# 21 1000026   C39             <NA>                                             
# 22 1000026   C50             <NA>                                             
# 23 1000026   C51             Structural Steel Contractor                      
# 24 1000026   C31             <NA>
```

My guess was that you'd prefer to keep "something" vice `NA`, so I defaulted to replacing the `NA`s with the classification when a description is missing. If your data has no such concerns, then you can skip that step (and just rename description to classification).

The long format is good for many things (esp `ggplot2` and similar "tidy" operations), but if you want it in a wide format, then

```r
out %>%
  group_by(LicenseNo) %>%
  mutate(rn = paste0("Classification", row_number())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(LicenseNo, names_from = rn, values_from = Classifications)
# # A tibble: 5 x 20
#   LicenseNo Classification1 Classification2 Classification3 Classification4 Classification5 Classification6 Classification7
#   <chr>     <chr>           <chr>           <chr>           <chr>           <chr>           <chr>           <chr>          
# 1 1000002   Well Drilling ~ <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>           
# 2 1000003   Cabinet, Millw~ <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>           
# 3 1000012   General Buildi~ <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>           
# 4 1000015   Welding Contra~ Structural Ste~ <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>           
# 5 1000026   Hazardous Subs~ Plumbing Contr~ Electrical Con~ General Engine~ General Buildi~ Well Drilling ~ Insulation and~
# # ... with 12 more variables: Classification8 <chr>, Classification9 <chr>, Classification10 <chr>, Classification11 <chr>,
# #   Classification12 <chr>, Classification13 <chr>, Classification14 <chr>, Classification15 <chr>, Classification16 <chr>,
# #   Classification17 <chr>, Classification18 <chr>, Classification19 <chr>
```

Comment: TY for your quick response r2evans been dealing with rlang issues and just got packages deleted and reinstalled to resolve. Agree duplicating the licenseNo can make graphing much easier

Comment: adjusted # 3 wide transformation based on the Descriptions, how do I adjust group by to retain other existing variables

Comment: `pivot_wider` supports widening on multiple columns, the docs and its website demonstrate the capability.